# CSS and image error - Doesn't show image

Tags: css, image

I got a little problem when trying to position my image, it does not show as i wanted, and i have been looking for at answer for a few hours. I want my picture to be shown were the arrows points: 
[image]
I want this image to be at 100% width, i just cannot make it appear like I want to. The closet I can compare it to look like is the facebook cover picture (Menus at top, a big image and some small soundclouds and facebook like i already have ;) ).
And sorry for my English :s

---- My html (Sorry if its un-readable, i will copy and upload everything on request) ----

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="default-css" href="default.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head> 
<div id="cover-image" class="clearfix"></div>
<footer id="site-footer">
<iframe  width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F83233916"></iframe>

<object height="81" width="100%"> 
    <param name="movie" value="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F83233916&amp;show_comments=true&amp;auto_play=false&amp;color=343538&amp;theme_color=343538&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_bmp=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;show_bmp=true"></param> 
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="transparent"></param> 
<embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F83233916&amp;show_comments=true&amp;auto_play=false&amp;color=343538&amp;theme_color=34353&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_bmp=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;show_bmp=true" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed>
</object>
- Control areal -
<div class="plugin_example" id="u_0_9"><div data-href="http://www.facebook.com/DjSalling"data-send="true" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark" class="fb-like >dark_background fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" fb-xfbml->state="rendered><span width="100%" height="61"><iframe id="f30076c07" name="f2303a14a8" scrolling="no" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 61px; width: 100%;" title="Like this content on Facebook." class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=113869198637480&amp;locale=da_DK&amp;sdk=joey&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D22%23cb%3Df20c4c7538%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fdevelopers.facebook.com%252Ff5cc88ac%26domain%3Ddevelopers.facebook.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDjSalling&amp;node_type=link&amp;width=450&amp;layout=standard&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;send=true
&amp;extended_social_context=false"></iframe></span></div></div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

---- CSS ----

```
#cover-image {
      background-image: url(background_cover.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: left top;
        }

#site-footer { position: relative; 
    position: absolute: bottom;
    background: url(footer-divider.png) center top no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0 200px 0;
    padding: 27px 0 0;
    clear: both;
        }

    #inner-footer { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
        }

        #inner-footer .content {
            color: #bcbcbc;
            background: #272729;
            background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.15);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding: 10px;

            height: 72px;

            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
```

Thanks everyone :)

**EDITS:**

@3rror404 Thanks, but i what the width to be at 100% so the images scaling moves at the size of your browser and automaticly downscales from lets say 2560x1600?

```
#cover-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(background_cover.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
```

Now height is at 400xp but not even close to be able to view the whole picture

As you can see here the width works, the height just doesn't

@Kamal I used your css, but when i drag my browser window back and forth i can see the image just gets cut off, and in a narrow browser window there is a big space from the soundcloud to the picture.

Comment: Which item is supposed to be the one you want shown properly?

Comment: You haven't given #cover-image a height. It will collapse to 0px as it has no content. You should give it a height matching that of your background image.

Comment: @3rror404 Indeed, First thing I thougt

Comment: @user2308933 whats the image cover url? Open and check the height then type on there `height:100px; [just an example]`

Comment: Not sure if you fixed the issue yet, but I was wondering if the image shows if you gave it a fixed height and width first. If it still doesn't - did you check if the filepath to the image was correct? And if it is, did you check if the images have the correct permission settings? (I ask this because I noticed on my end, that if the folder for my images doesn't have the correct permission settings, it won't display my images)

Comment: If you want to refer to facebook's (or any other site's) layout, include a snapshot of the layout you're aiming for. A change in the referred website will render your question incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure that i followed your problem.. but do you mean that the image ,that you are setting as background property should scale to the width of container??

```
#cover-image {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background-image: url(background_cover.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
background-position: left top;
```

should fit your background image width to container width.. is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want `background-size: cover`

```
#cover-image {
    height: 400px;
    background: url(background_cover.jpg) center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will force your background image to cover the entire container whilst maintaining aspect ratio and staying horizontally and vertically centered.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsn7H/2/) (Resize your browser)

---

EDIT

OK, if you don't care about maintining aspect ratio use `background-size: 100% 100%`

```
#cover-image {
    height: 400px;
    background: url(background_cover.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

This will scale your background image to 100% of the height and 100% width of the container even if that means stretching or squashing the image.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsn7H/7/)

Comment: Yea, well. When doing that you cuts out some of the image instead of re-sizing/re-scaling it as i want to :/

Comment: I got it :) But what command do you use if you want the picture to push down my footer if the picture expands?